# Is tensor product of irreducible and indecomposable representations indecomposable?

Tags: representation-theory

All representations are finite dimensional over a field $F$ of characteristic 0. Let $H < G$ be a normal finite index subgroup, $W$ a $G$-representation such that $W$ is an indecomposable $H$-representation and let $V$ be an irreducible $G/H$-representation. Is $V \otimes_F W$ an indecomposable $G$-representation?

In particular I would like this to be true for a profinite group $G$ and an open subgroup $H$ where all representations are continuous. But it seems like the topology shouldn't matter for this question.

Comment: Well the topology might actually come into question if $G$ is indeed profinite and the action is continuous, because then you have a Haar measure and so you can actually average things over $G$ so that irreducible = indecomposable.

Comment: @Max this is not true. Consider the unipotent action of $Z_p$ on $Q_p^2$.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was thinking of $F= \mathbb{ R, C}$ (where the Haar measure actually has meaning)

Comment: You probably want to add some "algebraically closed" or "absolutely" irreducible/indecomposable condition, or I don't think this is true even for finite groups.